# Cell.imageView.image doesn't automatically load when changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have code to change a tableView's cell's image in the foreground (after downloading the image in the background):

```
dispatch_queue_t background = dispatch_get_global_queue (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(background, ^{

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://whatever.jpg"]]];

            dispatch_queue_t foreground = dispatch_get_main_queue();

            dispatch_async(foreground, ^{
               cell.imageView.image = image;
            });
        });
```

Now I know the code works fine because it'll load when I delegate away from the tableview and come back. It'll also work (automatically load) if I set the cell.textLabel.text to something at the same time I'm setting the imageView, but for some reason just trying to change the cell image using blocks doesn't work.

Also it'll work if they're out of blocks, but I don't want to do that because of delays.

All help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `[cell.imageView setNeedsLayout:YES]` , other than that I can't see how your code won't work, I have the exact same code in one of my apps and it works fine.

Comment: That works perfectly! Gah, after so many hours such a simple line fixed it. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `[tableview reloadData];` when the block completes.

Comment: Tried that but all the cells disappear for some reason, thanks though